# address.replace is not a function

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, react

I'm not really sure why this web3 method is being called in my code and why it's not a function apparently.

Can anyone help me understand what the issue is here?

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): address.replace is not a function

**My react code calling my smart contract:**

```
var event = storehash.events.documentAdded()
    await storehash.methods.sendDocument(_ipfsLink, newDate).send({from: _account})
    event.watch(function(error, result) {
            if (!error)
                //this.setState({idForBlockchain: result.args.id})
                console.log(result);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe `_account` is the wrong type? It should be a public Ethereum address in a string (e.g. `"0x12345..."`).

Comment: The worrying part is I'm able to display _account on the screen and its correct, so I'm really not sure how it's getting a problem with it.

Comment: And what's its type? Try logging `typeof _account`.

Comment: Another guess: the address you used to initialize `storehash`?

Comment: Hmm, logging its type gave object back. So am I not getting it correct with `this.setState({account: await web3.eth.getAccounts()})` or do I need to change its type to string before I send it?

Comment: `web3.eth.getAccounts()` returns an array. Maybe you want `web3.eth.getAccounts()[0]`?

Comment: Okay doing `_account.toString` made the metamask interaction pop up! Thanks so much!